# How to add custom bullet to word document with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add custom bullet to my word document using apache poi.

I could add bullet with this code part

```
    CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
    cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
    CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
    cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
    cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("•");
    XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
    XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
    BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
    BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);
```

But i want to change the bullet format to in like this photo

[image: bullet]

Answer (score 1):

The

```
cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("•");
```

sets the bullet symbol. In this case the Unicode bullet `u\2022`. So if another symbol is needed, then set it there.

Word itself uses the special font Wingdings for special symbols here. There ANSI code is mapped to special glyph. For example ANSI code 216 (D8) is mapped to the glyph showing that arrow symbol. But that would need font settings for the `CTLvl`.

The simplest solution is using [equivalent Unicode characters](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html). Wingdings 216 is equivalent  to  Unicode `\u2B9A`. So

```
cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("\u2B9A");
```

should work.

If you really want using Wingdings as Word does, then following is needed:

```
cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("\uF0D8");
cTLvl.addNewRPr().addNewRFonts().setHAnsi("Wingdings");
cTLvl.getRPr().getRFontsArray(0).setAscii("Wingdings");
cTLvl.getRPr().getRFontsArray(0).setHint(STHint.DEFAULT);
```

This sets font Wingdings for the `cTLvl`.

Note the value is set `\uF0D8` and not `\u00D8`. This is used because  `\u00D8` would show Ø if Wingdings cannot be used. This could lead to irritations.